# Picking out information from text file using vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm using cmd to print the users network spec in to a text file using ipconfig > computer.txt. An Example of this would be

```
Windows IP Configuration


Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::cd7a:50b3:1284:865%12
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.26
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.0.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.1

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::5c3a:ae77:81:8cdf%11
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.25
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.12
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.1
```

How would I use this to find one of the adapters default gateway( x lines down and after then:

Not sure if this is right way of doing it.

If not, what is the best way to find the subnet mask/default gateway using vb.net

Comment: There are lower-level ways of getting to that information which will be more reliable and efficient.  Check here for lots of good ideas and links: http://www.msvisual.com/Installing-RAS-programmatically-t25743.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the format is always the same `String.IndexOf` and `String.Substring` are effcient ways:

```
Dim gateWays = From line In File.ReadLines("C:\Temp\data.txt")
               Skip 10
               Let gatewayIndex = line.IndexOf("Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :")
               Where gatewayIndex > -1
               Select line.Substring(gatewayIndex + "Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :".Length)
Dim firstGateWay = gateWays.FirstOrDefault
```

You can use [`Enumerable.Skip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985.aspx) to skip x-lines, in this example 10.

Comment: Specify _particular line_. A line after n-lines or after a line which contains a particular text?

Comment: @user1244772: Since you've mentioned "_x lines down_" i assume that you want to skip x lines. Edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want:

```
Private Function GetGateway(ByVal fileName As String) As String
    Dim sr As New System.IO.StreamReader(fileName)
    Dim foundEthernet As Boolean = False
    Dim gateway As String = ""

    Do Until sr.EndOfStream
        Dim line As String = sr.ReadLine()

        If line.Contains("Ethernet adapter LAN:") OrElse line.Contains("Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:") Then
            foundEthernet = True
        End If

        If foundEthernet Then
            If line.Contains("Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :") Then
                gateway = line.Substring(line.IndexOf(":") + 1).Trim
                Exit Do
            End If
        End If
    Loop
    sr.Close()

    Return gateway
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, as mellamokb mentioned, if you're running this application on the PC you're querying, you can use

```
System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces
```

to get at this information.